# Magento 2 backend language not applied

Tags: magento2, language

In a Magento2 system 2.2.0-dev I try to set the Backend language. In the account setting for the user I selected the language (interface locale) and saved it. Emptied cache etc, but its not applied? 
What am I missing here?
Or can this only be done through the command-line? And if so how?

Comment: Downgraded to 2.1.2 but still not able to change the language for the backend! 
Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it. Seems that there are no language packages in the Magento2 version. After installing a package with Composer it works.